# Team Foundation Server 2015 Upgrade

Tags: tfs, tfs-2015

I have a TFS 2015 installed in a Server.
Now, I want to upgrade it to TFS 2018 i na different Server.

I am planning to install TFS 2018 in the new machine, and than import the database from TFS 2015. This is an alternative to install TFS 2015 in the new machine, and than upgrade it to TFS 2018.

What do you think of my solution? Do you think that by installing TFS 2018 and than using the data in the database of TFS 2015 will let me make the upgrade successfully (Prtojects, Customizations, Configurations)?

Comment: Did you read Microsoft's upgrade documentation?

Comment: Can you point in the documentation URL. I haven't managed to find it...

Comment: I've found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs/server/upgrade/get-started

Comment: However, as I will install TFS in another machine (new installation) I wanted to know  if I could just install TFS 2018 and than connect it to the database.

Comment: You could easily do so, i've done the same when I migrated and upgraded TFS 2015. So you can just start the installation on another machine and then when it comes to the database, select your already existing database.

Comment: Ok, I'll try that. Thanks :)

Comment: When you did that, everything migrated successfully?

Answer (score 1):

I think that if you would like to do something like this, you need to setup the database on the new machine first, import the database of TFS 2015 to that database.
Then install TFS 2018, select that you already have a database and select the imported one.

The upgrade will go through your database and update a lot of different columns and rows, which is why you cannot expect it to work in the way you suggest.